# SQLite CTE limitations (Correlated Subqueries)

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression

I'm confused why Correlated Sub Queries work fine in SQL, but CTE's that emulate the same logic with dependencies, throw an error that says 'XYZ CTE doesn't exist'.

Error message: Error while executing SQL query on database 'BB_Data': no such table: CTE2

I could of course persist these to a view, but these are temporary transformations hence why I've chosen a CTE.

**Correlated Sub Query Approach which works fine**

```
SELECT * ,
arrival_year||"-"||month_transformed||"-"||day_transformed as arrival_date
FROM(

SELECT *,
CASE WHEN length(arrival_month_numeric) =1 THEN "0"||arrival_month_numeric ELSE arrival_month_numeric END as month_transformed,
CASE WHEN length(arrival_date_day_of_month) =1 THEN "0"||arrival_date_day_of_month ELSE arrival_date_day_of_month END as day_transformed
FROM
(
SELECT *,
CASE 
WHEN arrival_month = 'January'  THEN 1
WHEN arrival_month = 'February'  THEN 2
WHEN arrival_month = 'March'  THEN 3
WHEN arrival_month = 'April'  THEN 4
WHEN arrival_month = 'May'  THEN 5
WHEN arrival_month = 'June'  THEN 6
WHEN arrival_month = 'July'  THEN 7
WHEN arrival_month = 'August'  THEN 8
WHEN arrival_month = 'September'  THEN 9
WHEN arrival_month = 'October'  THEN 10
WHEN arrival_month = 'November'  THEN 11
WHEN arrival_month = 'December'  THEN 12
ELSE 0 END as arrival_month_numeric
FROM
booking_table))
```

**CTE Approach**

```
WITH CTE1 AS(
SELECT *,
    CASE 
    WHEN arrival_month = 'January'  THEN 1
    WHEN arrival_month = 'February'  THEN 2
    WHEN arrival_month = 'March'  THEN 3
    WHEN arrival_month = 'April'  THEN 4
    WHEN arrival_month = 'May'  THEN 5
    WHEN arrival_month = 'June'  THEN 6
    WHEN arrival_month = 'July'  THEN 7
    WHEN arrival_month = 'August'  THEN 8
    WHEN arrival_month = 'September'  THEN 9
    WHEN arrival_month = 'October'  THEN 10
    WHEN arrival_month = 'November'  THEN 11
    WHEN arrival_month = 'December'  THEN 12
    ELSE 0 END as arrival_month_numeric
    FROM
    booking_table),

    CTE2 AS(
    SELECT *,
        CASE WHEN length(arrival_month_numeric) =1 THEN "0"||arrival_month_numeric ELSE arrival_month_numeric END as month_transformed,
        CASE WHEN length(arrival_date_day_of_month) =1 THEN "0"||arrival_date_day_of_month ELSE arrival_date_day_of_month END as day_transformed
    FROM CTE1)
    
    SELECT * FROM CTE2;
```

Comment: Could you try to let,`CTE2` concat with the comma  like `,CTE2 AS(`

Comment: It works fine for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=50559e59a80220f7b10f7c6cd6da3b19

Comment: @D-Shih - I reset my SQLite instance and ran this again and now it works...
I have no idea why though and that is what troubles me...
But from an overall Syntactical perspective - you see no issues I take it?